# sql query to set the cell value as the difference between another cell in another column minus the prior result

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have tried the following query but it throws the error,

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the
>   subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

```
UPDATE dbo.SFData 
SET KPIperMonth =
    (SELECT KPIValue, KPIValue - LAG(KPIValue) OVER (ORDER BY SFID) PreviousValue
     from dbo.SFData)
```

what i have is a table as follows

```
SFID|KPIValue|KPIperMonth
---------------------
1   |1       |
2   |3       |
3   |5       |
```

the table above shows the cumulative sum of sales in months KPIValue.
I would like these results:

```
SFID|KPIValue|KPIperMonth
---------------------
1   |1       |1
2   |3       |2 (3-1)
3   |5       |2 (5-3)
```

Comment: Can you please add the error message that you received to your original post?

Comment: Hello! Microsoft server 2016

Comment: Error: Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Comment: Remove first KPIValue from the subquery's select list.

Comment: What type is the `KPIperMonth` column?

Comment: BTW, it's generally a bad idea to store values computed from other columns. Data redundancy, and risk of data inconsistency! I'd say create a _view_ instead, or have a _computed column_.

Comment: after removing i get error:Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: KPIperMonth is type decimal(18,3)

Comment: The subquery WHERE clause also needs a reference to the outer table's SFID.

Comment: Then see the answer from Barbaros Özhan below

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH Previous_KPI AS
(
    SELECT SFID, KPIValue, KPIValue - LAG(KPIValue,1,0) OVER (ORDER BY SFID) PreviousValue
    FROM SFData
)

UPDATE 
    SFData
SET 
    SFData.KPIperMonth = Previous_KPI.PreviousValue
FROM
    SFData 
    LEFT JOIN Previous_KPI
        ON SFData.SFID = Previous_KPI.SFID
```